# Error 11 when using pthread_create in TCP server

Tags: c, multithreading, tcp

I have a C app that listens to a TCP port and creates a new thread each time it accepts a new connection. It works OK initially, but after a while I start getting error code 11 from pthread_create.

There are no thread-related function calls inside the body of the thread function, and the log shows that there is a matching 'out' for every 'in'.

When it fails, I call the thread function that directly, and it works fine indefinitely on the main thread, so it seems unlikely that I am using up resources within the function. Any suggestions on what causes the error 11, and how to fix it?

This is the thread function:

```
void * tcp_process_message (void * arg) {
    MESSAGE_BUFFER * bp = (MESSAGE_BUFFER *) arg;
    USER_LOG (UL_INFO, "tpm in %d", bp - buffers);
    ...
    USER_LOG (UL_INFO, "tpm out %d", bp - buffers);
}
```

This is the section that creates threads: there is no other code that interacts with the new thread once it is created.

```
while(!cancel){
    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &from_addr, &fromsize); 
    if (!cancel) {
        MESSAGE_BUFFER * bp = allocate_message ();
        if (bp == NULL) {
            USER_LOG (UL_ERROR, "%s", "allocate_message failed");
            close(connfd);
        }
        else {
            bp->connfd = connfd;
            strcpy (bp->ip_addr, inet_ntoa(from_addr.sin_addr));
            int err = pthread_create (&tid, NULL, &tcp_process_message, (void *) bp);
            if (err) {
                USER_LOG (UL_ERROR, "thread create failed (%d)", err);
                tcp_process_message ((void *) bp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"It works OK initially, but after a while I start getting error code" - Tighten this up and give a proper [mcve]. For all we know you're not properly waiting/destroying the threads, and those resources are finite. Your result is `EAGAIN`, and in thread-speak that means you're out of thread resources. Odds are strong a service queue and dedicated thread pool is a far better match to your use case anyway.

Comment: Use `strerror(err)` to convert the error number to a meaningful string.

Answer (score 2):

When creating thread, the thread resource still exist even after the thread function exits.

Some piece of code must either wait for the thread using `pthread_join(the_thread);` or, it must detach the thread and let it die once its function exits: `pthread_detach(the_thread);`.

If not done, the thread remain in the system and the system will soon run out of resources and won't be able to create new threads anymore.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of that: I assumed that the thread resource was released when the function exits. That looks like my problem. I will try adding a pthread_detach.